# How to do Maven install or deploy only, without re-package/re-test?

Tags: maven

Sometimes I wanted to deploy, but I typed `mvn package`.

Sometimes I want to deploy to another alternative repository (using `mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=...`), immediately after the default deploy.

So I really don't want to package and test them again, because they are just succeeded. The result jars are just there, in the `target/` directory. I hope I can deploy them.

I know there is `deploy:deploy-file`, but that's inconvenient to use, I don't want to specify groupId, artifactId again on the command line. It doesn't work for large project which contains a lot of jars to deploy, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [maven.test.skip](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/test/) command line flag to skips tests:

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true install
```

Use the [maven.repo.list](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/artifact/properties.html) command line flag to add another repository:

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.list=
```

Comment: But this will only skip tests but still perform packaging, right?

Comment: This will run the whole pipeline again, skipping tests. Some of the plugins may rely on previous build-results, many won't. Most of the standard-plugins will obey the flag and won't run again, but many other plugins will ignore it and thus will run again. Also, some of the maven plugins, which are skipped due to this flag, should actually run (partially) none-the-less, but won't. For instance, the test-jar goal is skipped when tests are skipped, and thus the test-jar is not attached to the list of release-artifacts and is thus not deployed by "mvn deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true".